# Why does CCSD work, but not CCSD(T), after reading an FCIDUMP in PySCF?

Tags: python, software-assistance, pyscf, coupled-cluster, fcidump

## CCSD(T) works after an RHF calculation:

### Input:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# Author: Nike Dattani, nike@hpqc.org

import pyscf
from pyscf import gto, scf, ao2mo, cc

mol = gto.Mole()
mol.atom = ''' O
               H  1  0.9576257
               H  1  0.9576257  2 104.51 '''
mol.unit = 'angstrom'
mol.basis = 'STO-3G'
mol.charge = 0
mol.spin = 0
mol.verbose = 9
mol.symmetry = True
mol.symmetry_subgroup = 'C2v'
name = 'out'
#mol.output = name+'.txt' # only worked up to end of SCF (CC output went to stdout)
mol.build()

#####################
## Hartree-Fock:
#####################

mf = mol.RHF().set(chkfile = name + '.chk')
mf.kernel()

#####################
## post-Hartree-Fock:
#####################

mcc = cc.CCSD(mf).set(frozen=1,verbose=9)
e = mcc.kernel()
et = mcc.ccsd_t() # works only when not reading FCIDUMP file.

#####################
## END OF INPUT 
#####################
```

### Output:

**I've included the last few lines here, but you can see a link to the full output file in the "Availability of files" section of this post. Notice the CCSD(T) energy at the end:**

```
cycle = 7  E_corr(CCSD) = -0.0493362838011038  dE = -8.86095146e-08  norm(t1,t2) = 2.47391e-06
    CPU time for CCSD iter      3.58 sec, wall time      0.06 sec
    CPU time for CCSD     25.37 sec, wall time      0.46 sec
CCSD converged
E(CCSD) = -75.01232875135784  E_corr = -0.0493362838011038
    CPU time for CCSD integral transformation      4.66 sec, wall time      0.08 sec
irreps of each MO [0 3 0 2 0 3]
_sort_eri max_memory 3528.17  blksize 2
    CPU time for transpose 0:2      0.69 sec, wall time      0.01 sec
    CPU time for CCSD(T) sort_eri      1.39 sec, wall time      0.03 sec
max_memory 3920 MB (79 MB in use)
    CPU time for contract 0:2,0:2      0.14 sec, wall time      0.00 sec
    CPU time for CCSD(T)      1.79 sec, wall time      0.04 sec
CCSD(T) correction = -6.75066430370798e-05
```

## CCSD works, but not (T) when using FCIDUMP:

### Input:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# Author: Nike Dattani, nike@hpqc.org

import pyscf
from pyscf import gto, scf, ao2mo, cc

mol = gto.Mole()
mol.atom = ''' O
               H  1  0.9576257
               H  1  0.9576257  2 104.51 '''
mol.unit = 'angstrom'
mol.basis = 'STO-3G'
mol.charge = 0
mol.spin = 0
mol.verbose = 9
mol.symmetry = True
mol.symmetry_subgroup = 'C2v'
name = 'out'
#mol.output = name+'.txt' # only worked up to end of SCF (CC output went to stdout)
mol.build()

#####################
## Hartree-Fock:
#####################

mf = mol.RHF().set(chkfile = name + '.chk')
mf.kernel()

pyscf.tools.fcidump.from_chkfile(name+'.fcidump',name+'.chk', tol=1e-18, float_format=' %.16g', molpro_orbsym=False, orbsym=None)
mf = pyscf.tools.fcidump.to_scf(name+'.fcidump', molpro_orbsym=False, mf=None)
mf.run()

#####################
## post-Hartree-Fock:
#####################

mcc = cc.CCSD(mf).set(frozen=1,verbose=9)
e = mcc.kernel()
et = mcc.ccsd_t() # works only when not reading FCIDUMP file.

#####################
## END OF INPUT 
#####################
```

### Output:

**Notice that the CCSD energy is `-75.012328751` which agrees with the above case (when no FCIDUMP file was used) in all digits shown:**

```
#INFO: **** input file is /home/nike/QCBugs/Issue022/inp_withDump.py ****
#!/usr/bin/env python
# Author: Nike Dattani, nike@hpqc.org

import pyscf
from pyscf import gto, scf, ao2mo, cc

mol = gto.Mole()
mol.atom = ''' O
               H  1  0.9576257
               H  1  0.9576257  2 104.51 '''
mol.unit = 'angstrom'
mol.basis = 'STO-3G'
mol.charge = 0
mol.spin = 0
mol.verbose = 9
mol.symmetry = True
mol.symmetry_subgroup = 'C2v'
name = 'out'
#mol.output = name+'.txt' # only worked up to end of SCF (CC output went to stdout)
mol.build()

#####################
## Hartree-Fock:
#####################

mf = mol.RHF().set(chkfile = name + '.chk')
mf.kernel()

pyscf.tools.fcidump.from_chkfile(name+'.fcidump',name+'.chk', tol=1e-18, float_format=' %.16g', molpro_orbsym=False, orbsym=None)
mf = pyscf.tools.fcidump.to_scf(name+'.fcidump', molpro_orbsym=False, mf=None)
mf.run()

#####################
## post-Hartree-Fock:
#####################

mcc = cc.CCSD(mf).set(frozen=1,verbose=9)
e = mcc.kernel()
et = mcc.ccsd_t() # works only when not reading FCIDUMP file.

#####################
## END OF INPUT 
#####################
#INFO: ******************** input file end ********************


System: uname_result(system='Linux', node='cedar1.cedar.computecanada.ca', release='3.10.0-1160.80.1.el7.x86_64', version='#1 SMP Tue Nov 8 15:48:59 UTC 2022', machine='x86_64', processor='')  Threads 64
Python 3.8.10 (default, Jun 16 2021, 14:20:20) 
[GCC 9.3.0]
numpy 1.23.0  scipy 1.9.3
Date: Sat Jan 21 14:55:08 2023
PySCF version 2.1.1
PySCF path  /home/nike/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyscf

[CONFIG] DEBUG = False
[CONFIG] MAX_MEMORY = 4000
[CONFIG] TMPDIR = /tmp
[CONFIG] UNIT = angstrom
[CONFIG] VERBOSE = 3
[CONFIG] conf_file = None
[INPUT] verbose = 9
[INPUT] max_memory = 4000 
[INPUT] num. atoms = 3
[INPUT] num. electrons = 10
[INPUT] charge = 0
[INPUT] spin (= nelec alpha-beta = 2S) = 0
[INPUT] symmetry True subgroup C2v
[INPUT] Mole.unit = angstrom
[INPUT] Symbol           X                Y                Z      unit          X                Y                Z       unit  Magmom
[INPUT]  1 O      0.000000000000   0.000000000000   0.000000000000 AA    0.000000000000   0.000000000000   0.000000000000 Bohr   0.0
[INPUT]  2 H      0.957625700000   0.000000000000   0.000000000000 AA    1.809650302845   0.000000000000   0.000000000000 Bohr   0.0
[INPUT]  3 H     -0.239932136496   0.000000000000   0.927081199883 AA   -0.453406026459   0.000000000000   1.751929563013 Bohr   0.0
[INPUT] ---------------- BASIS SET ---------------- 
[INPUT] l, kappa, [nprim/nctr], expnt,             c_1 c_2 ...
[INPUT] O
[INPUT] 0    0    [3    /1   ]  130.70932         0.15432897
                                23.808861         0.53532814
                                6.4436083         0.44463454
[INPUT] 0    0    [3    /1   ]  5.0331513         -0.09996723
                                1.1695961         0.39951283
                                0.380389          0.70011547
[INPUT] 1    0    [3    /1   ]  5.0331513         0.15591627
                                1.1695961         0.60768372
                                0.380389          0.39195739
[INPUT] H
[INPUT] 0    0    [3    /1   ]  3.42525091        0.15432897
                                0.62391373        0.53532814
                                0.1688554         0.44463454

nuclear repulsion = 9.19090095527734
point group symmetry = C2v
symmetry origin: [0.13562443 0.         0.17519296]
symmetry axis x: [-0. -1. -0.]
symmetry axis y: [ 0.790743    0.         -0.61214828]
symmetry axis z: [0.61214828 0.         0.790743  ]
num. orbitals of irrep A1 = 4
num. orbitals of irrep B1 = 1
num. orbitals of irrep B2 = 2
number of shells = 5
number of NR pGTOs = 21
number of NR cGTOs = 7
basis = STO-3G
ecp = {}
bas 0, expnt(s) = [130.70932    23.808861    6.4436083]
bas 1, expnt(s) = [5.0331513 1.1695961 0.380389 ]
bas 2, expnt(s) = [5.0331513 1.1695961 0.380389 ]
bas 3, expnt(s) = [3.42525091 0.62391373 0.1688554 ]
bas 4, expnt(s) = [3.42525091 0.62391373 0.1688554 ]
CPU time:         0.61
arg.atm = [[ 8 20  1 23  0  0]
 [ 1 24  1 27  0  0]
 [ 1 28  1 31  0  0]]
arg.bas = [[ 0  0  3  1  0 32 35  0]
 [ 0  0  3  1  0 38 41  0]
 [ 0  1  3  1  0 44 47  0]
 [ 1  0  3  1  0 50 53  0]
 [ 2  0  3  1  0 50 53  0]]
arg.env = [  0.           0.           0.           0.           0.
   0.           0.           0.           0.           0.
   0.           0.           0.           0.           0.
   0.           0.           0.           0.           0.
   0.           0.           0.           0.           1.8096503
   0.           0.           0.          -0.45340603   0.
   1.75192956   0.         130.70932     23.808861     6.4436083
  15.07274649  14.57770167   4.54323359   5.0331513    1.1695961
   0.380389    -0.848697     1.13520079   0.85675304   5.0331513
   1.1695961    0.380389     3.42906571   2.15628856   0.34159239
   3.42525091   0.62391373   0.1688554    0.98170675   0.94946401
   0.29590645]
ecpbas  = []


******** <class 'pyscf.scf.hf_symm.SymAdaptedRHF'> ********
method = SymAdaptedRHF-RHF
initial guess = minao
damping factor = 0
level_shift factor = 0
DIIS = <class 'pyscf.scf.diis.CDIIS'>
diis_start_cycle = 1
diis_space = 8
SCF conv_tol = 1e-09
SCF conv_tol_grad = None
SCF max_cycles = 50
direct_scf = True
direct_scf_tol = 1e-13
chkfile to save SCF result = out.chk
max_memory 4000 MB (current use 73 MB)
Freeze 0 electrons in irreps []
    10 free electrons in irreps A1 B1 B2
Set gradient conv threshold to 3.16228e-05
Nelec from initial guess = 9.86091385128042
E1 = -120.44790124439959  E_coul = 36.420426001819735
init E= -74.8365742873025
cond(S) = 5.636127957820105
    CPU time for initialize scf      3.84 sec, wall time      0.11 sec
HOMO (B1) = -0.393165985098286  LUMO (A1) = 0.426534016701304
irrep_nelec = [6, 2, 2]
A1 nocc = 3  HOMO = -0.529231880970381  LUMO = 0.426534016701304
   mo_energy = [-20.58868486  -1.58169821  -0.52923188   0.42653402]
B1 nocc = 1  HOMO = -0.393165985098286
   mo_energy = [-0.39316599]
B2 nocc = 1  HOMO = -0.70700906241869  LUMO = 0.535461984106062
   mo_energy = [-0.70700906  0.53546198]
E1 = -123.52134582056792  E_coul = 39.41763506881344
cycle= 1 E= -74.9128097964771  delta_E= -0.0762  |g|= 0.37  |ddm|= 1.69
    CPU time for cycle= 1      1.52 sec, wall time      0.03 sec
diis-norm(errvec)=0.396528
diis-c [-0.15723468  1.        ]
HOMO (B1) = -0.267738785133512  LUMO (A1) = 0.644179976979969
irrep_nelec = [6, 2, 2]
A1 nocc = 3  HOMO = -0.352143944372835  LUMO = 0.644179976979969
   mo_energy = [-19.99464164  -1.18585095  -0.35214394   0.64417998]
B1 nocc = 1  HOMO = -0.267738785133512
   mo_energy = [-0.26773879]
B2 nocc = 1  HOMO = -0.568463618483647  LUMO = 0.78199967411182
   mo_energy = [-0.56846362  0.78199967]
E1 = -122.28168196574782  E_coul = 38.128317769163004
cycle= 2 E= -74.9624632413075  delta_E= -0.0497  |g|= 0.0425  |ddm|= 0.56
    CPU time for cycle= 2      1.37 sec, wall time      0.03 sec
diis-norm(errvec)=0.04803
diis-c [-0.00136375  0.07217221  0.92782779]
HOMO (B1) = -0.389540380152414  LUMO (A1) = 0.605437533093365
irrep_nelec = [6, 2, 2]
A1 nocc = 3  HOMO = -0.45142028023944  LUMO = 0.605437533093365
   mo_energy = [-20.23992255  -1.26623695  -0.45142028   0.60543753]
B1 nocc = 1  HOMO = -0.389540380152414
   mo_energy = [-0.38954038]
B2 nocc = 1  HOMO = -0.619149296689157  LUMO = 0.740674985160102
   mo_energy = [-0.6191493   0.74067499]
E1 = -122.36417637689611  E_coul = 38.21031049049565
cycle= 3 E= -74.9629649311231  delta_E= -0.000502  |g|= 0.00858  |ddm|= 0.0428
    CPU time for cycle= 3      1.40 sec, wall time      0.03 sec
diis-norm(errvec)=0.00911032
diis-c [-1.16690863e-07 -2.14458345e-02 -3.04583446e-01  1.32602928e+00]
HOMO (B1) = -0.39123899548012  LUMO (A1) = 0.605339731487355
irrep_nelec = [6, 2, 2]
A1 nocc = 3  HOMO = -0.453040362493816  LUMO = 0.605339731487355
   mo_energy = [-20.24189604  -1.26825133  -0.45304036   0.60533973]
B1 nocc = 1  HOMO = -0.39123899548012
   mo_energy = [-0.391239]
B2 nocc = 1  HOMO = -0.617822333820714  LUMO = 0.742000301689417
   mo_energy = [-0.61782233  0.7420003 ]
E1 = -122.36388789989842  E_coul = 38.209994478823994
cycle= 4 E= -74.9629924657971  delta_E= -2.75e-05  |g|= 6.36e-05  |ddm|= 0.0153
    CPU time for cycle= 4      1.44 sec, wall time      0.03 sec
diis-norm(errvec)=6.74546e-05
diis-c [-1.26810441e-09  1.44163187e-03  1.86026098e-02 -8.35947904e-02
  1.06355055e+00]
HOMO (B1) = -0.391219211832674  LUMO (A1) = 0.605260710774646
irrep_nelec = [6, 2, 2]
A1 nocc = 3  HOMO = -0.452963884631979  LUMO = 0.605260710774646
   mo_energy = [-20.24179211  -1.26819569  -0.45296388   0.60526071]
B1 nocc = 1  HOMO = -0.391219211832674
   mo_energy = [-0.39121921]
B2 nocc = 1  HOMO = -0.617681162161389  LUMO = 0.741859345734213
   mo_energy = [-0.61768116  0.74185935]
E1 = -122.36402357493989  E_coul = 38.210130152276335
cycle= 5 E= -74.9629924673862  delta_E= -1.59e-09  |g|= 1.47e-05  |ddm|= 0.000101
    CPU time for cycle= 5      1.48 sec, wall time      0.03 sec
diis-norm(errvec)=1.4269e-05
diis-c [-6.89862228e-11  3.78913368e-04  5.83088134e-03 -2.43547175e-02
 -2.27714492e-01  1.24585941e+00]
HOMO (B1) = -0.391222285213995  LUMO (A1) = 0.605265319359792
irrep_nelec = [6, 2, 2]
A1 nocc = 3  HOMO = -0.452965937366619  LUMO = 0.605265319359792
   mo_energy = [-20.2417999   -1.26820027  -0.45296594   0.60526532]
B1 nocc = 1  HOMO = -0.391222285213995
   mo_energy = [-0.39122229]
B2 nocc = 1  HOMO = -0.617689752981301  LUMO = 0.741862533680629
   mo_energy = [-0.61768975  0.74186253]
E1 = -122.36401253996894  E_coul = 38.21011911714349
cycle= 6 E= -74.9629924675481  delta_E= -1.62e-10  |g|= 3.68e-06  |ddm|= 4.23e-05
    CPU time for cycle= 6      1.48 sec, wall time      0.03 sec
HOMO (B1) = -0.391223261310395  LUMO (A1) = 0.605266801274786
irrep_nelec = [6, 2, 2]
A1 nocc = 3  HOMO = -0.452967068734555  LUMO = 0.605266801274786
   mo_energy = [-20.24180249  -1.26820185  -0.45296707   0.6052668 ]
B1 nocc = 1  HOMO = -0.391223261310395
   mo_energy = [-0.39122326]
B2 nocc = 1  HOMO = -0.617692480658258  LUMO = 0.741864183562906
   mo_energy = [-0.61769248  0.74186418]
E1 = -122.36400935331618  E_coul = 38.210115930482104
Extra cycle  E= -74.9629924675567  delta_E= -8.63e-12  |g|= 1.59e-06  |ddm|= 8.18e-06
    CPU time for scf_cycle     14.05 sec, wall time      0.32 sec
    CPU time for SCF     14.06 sec, wall time      0.32 sec
converged SCF energy = -74.9629924675567
irreps of each MO [0 0 3 0 2 0 3]
Parsing out.fcidump
converged SCF energy = -74.9629924675587

******** <class 'pyscf.cc.ccsd.CCSD'> ********
CC2 = 0
CCSD nocc = 4, nmo = 6
frozen orbitals 1
max_cycle = 50
direct = 0
conv_tol = 1e-07
conv_tol_normt = 1e-05
diis_space = 6
diis_start_cycle = 0
diis_start_energy_diff = 1e+09
max_memory 4000 MB (current use 81 MB)
total FLOPs 19520.0
    CPU time for CCSD integral transformation      3.97 sec, wall time      0.07 sec
Init t2, MP2 energy = -74.998421719993  E_corr(MP2) -0.0354292524343585
    CPU time for init mp2      0.02 sec, wall time      0.00 sec
Init E_corr(CCSD) = -0.0354292524343585
    CPU time for vvvv [0:1]      0.56 sec, wall time      0.01 sec
    CPU time for vvvv [1:2]      1.50 sec, wall time      0.03 sec
    CPU time for vvvv      2.10 sec, wall time      0.04 sec
max_memory 3918 MB,  nocc,nvir = 4,2  blksize = 2
    CPU time for vovv [0:2]      0.49 sec, wall time      0.01 sec
    CPU time for ovvv      0.73 sec, wall time      0.01 sec
max_memory 3918 MB,  nocc,nvir = 4,2  blksize = 2
    CPU time for voov [0:2]      0.14 sec, wall time      0.00 sec
    CPU time for update t1 t2      2.97 sec, wall time      0.06 sec
DIIS for step 0
cycle = 1  E_corr(CCSD) = -0.0447960700300642  dE = -0.0093668176  norm(t1,t2) = 0.0288404
    CPU time for CCSD iter      3.87 sec, wall time      0.07 sec
    CPU time for vvvv [0:1]      0.58 sec, wall time      0.01 sec
    CPU time for vvvv [1:2]      1.47 sec, wall time      0.03 sec
    CPU time for vvvv      2.09 sec, wall time      0.04 sec
max_memory 3918 MB,  nocc,nvir = 4,2  blksize = 2
    CPU time for vovv [0:2]      0.48 sec, wall time      0.01 sec
    CPU time for ovvv      0.73 sec, wall time      0.01 sec
max_memory 3918 MB,  nocc,nvir = 4,2  blksize = 2
    CPU time for voov [0:2]      0.13 sec, wall time      0.00 sec
    CPU time for update t1 t2      2.94 sec, wall time      0.06 sec
diis-c [-1.08058489e-04  1.00000000e+00]
DIIS for step 1
cycle = 2  E_corr(CCSD) = -0.0476847828331966  dE = -0.0028887128  norm(t1,t2) = 0.0103951
    CPU time for CCSD iter      3.84 sec, wall time      0.07 sec
    CPU time for vvvv [0:1]      0.59 sec, wall time      0.01 sec
    CPU time for vvvv [1:2]      1.49 sec, wall time      0.03 sec
    CPU time for vvvv      2.12 sec, wall time      0.04 sec
max_memory 3918 MB,  nocc,nvir = 4,2  blksize = 2
    CPU time for vovv [0:2]      0.59 sec, wall time      0.01 sec
    CPU time for ovvv      0.73 sec, wall time      0.01 sec
max_memory 3918 MB,  nocc,nvir = 4,2  blksize = 2
    CPU time for voov [0:2]      0.13 sec, wall time      0.00 sec
    CPU time for update t1 t2      2.98 sec, wall time      0.05 sec
diis-c [-1.86787238e-06 -6.34417047e-01  1.63441705e+00]
DIIS for step 2
cycle = 3  E_corr(CCSD) = -0.0493281778291895  dE = -0.001643395  norm(t1,t2) = 0.004227
    CPU time for CCSD iter      3.87 sec, wall time      0.07 sec
    CPU time for vvvv [0:1]      0.60 sec, wall time      0.01 sec
    CPU time for vvvv [1:2]      1.61 sec, wall time      0.03 sec
    CPU time for vvvv      2.23 sec, wall time      0.04 sec
max_memory 3918 MB,  nocc,nvir = 4,2  blksize = 2
    CPU time for vovv [0:2]      0.39 sec, wall time      0.01 sec
    CPU time for ovvv      0.61 sec, wall time      0.01 sec
max_memory 3918 MB,  nocc,nvir = 4,2  blksize = 2
    CPU time for voov [0:2]      0.13 sec, wall time      0.00 sec
    CPU time for update t1 t2      2.96 sec, wall time      0.05 sec
diis-c [-7.50388430e-08  4.30384287e-01 -1.16894742e+00  1.73856314e+00]
DIIS for step 3
cycle = 4  E_corr(CCSD) = -0.0493382688445465  dE = -1.00910154e-05  norm(t1,t2) = 0.000646334
    CPU time for CCSD iter      3.84 sec, wall time      0.07 sec
    CPU time for vvvv [0:1]      0.61 sec, wall time      0.01 sec
    CPU time for vvvv [1:2]      1.49 sec, wall time      0.03 sec
    CPU time for vvvv      2.13 sec, wall time      0.04 sec
max_memory 3918 MB,  nocc,nvir = 4,2  blksize = 2
    CPU time for vovv [0:2]      0.47 sec, wall time      0.01 sec
    CPU time for ovvv      0.71 sec, wall time      0.01 sec
max_memory 3918 MB,  nocc,nvir = 4,2  blksize = 2
    CPU time for voov [0:2]      0.13 sec, wall time      0.00 sec
    CPU time for update t1 t2      2.97 sec, wall time      0.05 sec
diis-c [-9.52646963e-10 -1.43883755e-01  3.99052284e-01 -6.72110757e-01
  1.41694223e+00]
DIIS for step 4
cycle = 5  E_corr(CCSD) = -0.0493369549300818  dE = 1.31391446e-06  norm(t1,t2) = 9.16421e-05
    CPU time for CCSD iter      3.88 sec, wall time      0.07 sec
    CPU time for vvvv [0:1]      0.60 sec, wall time      0.01 sec
    CPU time for vvvv [1:2]      1.51 sec, wall time      0.03 sec
    CPU time for vvvv      2.14 sec, wall time      0.04 sec
max_memory 3918 MB,  nocc,nvir = 4,2  blksize = 2
    CPU time for vovv [0:2]      0.55 sec, wall time      0.01 sec
    CPU time for ovvv      0.74 sec, wall time      0.01 sec
max_memory 3918 MB,  nocc,nvir = 4,2  blksize = 2
    CPU time for voov [0:2]      0.13 sec, wall time      0.00 sec
    CPU time for update t1 t2      3.01 sec, wall time      0.05 sec
diis-c [-3.43384042e-11  3.55433625e-02 -9.83589196e-02  1.69088982e-01
 -3.81924433e-01  1.27565101e+00]
DIIS for step 5
cycle = 6  E_corr(CCSD) = -0.0493361950942754  dE = 7.59835806e-07  norm(t1,t2) = 9.03218e-06
    CPU time for CCSD iter      3.91 sec, wall time      0.07 sec
    CPU time for vvvv [0:1]      0.59 sec, wall time      0.01 sec
    CPU time for vvvv [1:2]      1.47 sec, wall time      0.03 sec
    CPU time for vvvv      2.10 sec, wall time      0.04 sec
max_memory 3918 MB,  nocc,nvir = 4,2  blksize = 2
    CPU time for vovv [0:2]      0.47 sec, wall time      0.01 sec
    CPU time for ovvv      0.71 sec, wall time      0.01 sec
max_memory 3918 MB,  nocc,nvir = 4,2  blksize = 2
    CPU time for voov [0:2]      0.13 sec, wall time      0.00 sec
    CPU time for update t1 t2      2.94 sec, wall time      0.05 sec
diis-c [-9.65793511e-13 -7.08208773e-03  1.94817874e-02 -3.55306407e-02
  8.95997177e-02 -5.61950607e-01  1.49548183e+00]
DIIS for step 6
cycle = 7  E_corr(CCSD) = -0.0493362837053574  dE = -8.8611082e-08  norm(t1,t2) = 2.4739e-06
    CPU time for CCSD iter      3.82 sec, wall time      0.07 sec
    CPU time for CCSD     27.04 sec, wall time      0.49 sec
CCSD converged
E(CCSD) = -75.01232875126405  E_corr = -0.04933628370535739
    CPU time for CCSD integral transformation      3.84 sec, wall time      0.07 sec
Overwritten attributes  get_ovlp get_hcore  of <class 'pyscf.scf.hf_symm.SymAdaptedRHF'>
/home/nike/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyscf/gto/mole.py:1193: UserWarning: Function mol.dumps drops attribute energy_nuc because it is not JSON-serializable
  warnings.warn(msg)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./inp_withDump.py", line 39, in <module>
    et = mcc.ccsd_t() # works only when not reading FCIDUMP file.
  File "/home/nike/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyscf/cc/ccsd.py", line 1129, in ccsd_t
    return ccsd_t.kernel(self, eris, t1, t2, self.verbose)
  File "/home/nike/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyscf/cc/ccsd_t.py", line 51, in kernel
    orbsym = _sort_eri(mycc, eris, nocc, nvir, eris_vvop, log)
  File "/home/nike/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyscf/cc/ccsd_t.py", line 140, in _sort_eri
    orbsym = symm.addons.label_orb_symm(mol, mol.irrep_id, mol.symm_orb,
  File "/home/nike/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyscf/symm/addons.py", line 70, in label_orb_symm
    s_mo = numpy.dot(s, mo)
  File "<__array_function__ internals>", line 180, in dot
ValueError: shapes (0,0) and (7,6) not aligned: 0 (dim 1) != 7 (dim 0)
```

## Availability of files

All input and output files, including also the FCIDUMP and `.chk` files which are not included above, are available both at QCBugs [here](https://github.com/HPQC-LABS/QCBugs/tree/master/Issue022), and at MMSE's Modeling Matters Git repository [here](https://github.com/HPQC-LABS/Modeling_Matters/tree/master/10277). (In the future I may connect those two folders [if this question gets answered](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75191754/1271772)).

## Question

The final lines of the traceback for the attempt at calculating the (T) correction to CCSD after reading the integrals from an FCIDUMP file are here (copied from the end of the above output):

```
  File "/home/nike/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyscf/symm/addons.py", line 70, in label_orb_symm
    s_mo = numpy.dot(s, mo)
  File "<__array_function__ internals>", line 180, in dot
ValueError: shapes (0,0) and (7,6) not aligned: 0 (dim 1) != 7 (dim 0)
```

##### Why are those shapes not aligned for the (T) correction, but are fine for the CCSD calculation?

Comment: I have not used PySCF, but from following your traceback, the `s` in `numpy.dot(s,mo)` is the AO overlap matrix and the code seems to think this an entirely empty array. I'm speculating, but I think when reading the FCIDUMP, it doesn't need to/doesn't have enough info to generate the AO overlap matrix. so it leaves it blank and when it tries to form `s_mo` it fails. It seems like this is a bug, as it should just be able to fallback to making `s_mo` using [mf.get_ovlp](https://github.com/pyscf/pyscf/blob/master/pyscf/tools/fcidump.py#L343) which would have been defined in `to_scf`.

Comment: @Tyberius thanks for looking into it! The `FCIDUMP` should contain the integrals after the AO->MO transformation, and they should contain enough information to calculate the (T) correction to CCSD. It looks like it runs [`s = mol.intor_symmetric('int1e_ovlp')`](https://github.com/pyscf/pyscf/blob/9a8ebf14724b3d49eeb4a3719d1234c99df6e3e9/pyscf/symm/addons.py#L69) which makes it [become the overlap matrix](https://github.com/pyscf/pyscf/blob/master/pyscf/scf/hf.py#L337) which is empty. This all seems to be for some symmetry labeling of the orbitals that was not required for CCSD without (T).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

FCIDUMP only contains limited information about the system (e.g. numbers of orbitals and electrons, spatial symmetries of orbitals, etc.) and 1- and 2-electron integrals in MO basis. The FCIDUMP format is defined in [Comp. Phys. Commun. 54, 75 (1989)](https://doi.org/10.1016/0010-4655(89)90033-7). As @Tyberius and @NikeDattani discussed, FCIDUMP doesn't have enough information to recover atomic positions or AO basis. Thus, [`to_scf()`](https://github.com/pyscf/pyscf/blob/c0c4dbcb97b5725b5bbec3257b78f18c63663c76/pyscf/tools/fcidump.py#L310) only creates a Mole object with empty atoms/basis, which is why [`mol.intor_symmetric('int1e_ovlp')`](https://github.com/pyscf/pyscf/blob/c0c4dbcb97b5725b5bbec3257b78f18c63663c76/pyscf/symm/addons.py#L69) returns an empty overlap matrix `s` that leads to the ValueError in `s_mo = numpy.dot(s, mo)`.

A simple solution, as suggested by @Tyberius, is to use `mf.get_ovlp()` to get the overlap matrix instead. `mf.get_ovlp()` is already redefined in [`to_scf()`](https://github.com/pyscf/pyscf/blob/c0c4dbcb97b5725b5bbec3257b78f18c63663c76/pyscf/tools/fcidump.py#L343) to return an identity matrix (think of the orthonormal MO orbitals as the new AO basis). I've made a [pull request](https://github.com/pyscf/pyscf/pull/1580) to reflect this change.

Update 1/26/2023: The pull request has been merged into `master` branch.